# Issue with returning object from a function in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

i am little confused about my code:

Here is some function from my controller:

```
  public void signIn(string userName, string userPass)
        {
            User user = new User();
            user.getUser(userName , userPass);

            if (user.userName != null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("/Home/Menu");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("/Index/Index?Fail=" + "fail");
            }
        }
```

the " user.getUser" suppose to return a User object.. here is the code from my Model directory:

```
public class User
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string userPass { get; set; }

    public User getUser(string name , string pass)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        var db = client.GetDatabase("testdb");
        var coll = db.GetCollection<User>("user");

        List<User> list = coll.Find(x => x.userName == name && x.userPass == pass).ToList<User>();


        User uObj = new User();
        uObj = list.FirstOrDefault();

        return uObj;
    }
}
```

when i am debugging the code i can see the uJob object contain values. but when the function end and i return to the controller i see that the user object contain only null values, and the condition - "   if (user.userName != null)" is returning FALSE!.. instead of TRUE..

i would like to get some help. Thanks !

Comment: Because you do not assign the result of `user.getUser()` to anything and you only referring the the new `User` you initialized. You could use `User user - new User().getUser(userName , userPass);

Comment: You're actually creating 3 User objects here!  You create a dummy one on which to call "getUser( )" (I would consider making this static), then another one just before you replace it with the first one from the list returned from the database. But the actual problem is that you're then testing against the dummy one you first created rather the one you returned from with getUser().

Comment: _"i am little confused about my code"_ - so am I. Why are you implementing the active record pattern using an instance method? You'd first have to `new` a dummy user in order to query an actual user, of which a new instance is returned. Then you're not properly hashing your passwords. Please go read a C#, OO and security book or two before trying to invent an authentication system.

Comment: Also, if a user enters an unknown username or password, `list.FirstOrDefault()` will return `null` and `if (user.userName != null)` will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you assign the value returned by the getUser method in calling program like this

```
user = user.getUser(userName , userPass);
```

Or you change the code in Model like this

```
public class User
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string userPass { get; set; }

    public void getUser(string name , string pass)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        var db = client.GetDatabase("testdb");
        var coll = db.GetCollection<User>("user");

        var user = coll.FirstOrDefault(x => x.userName == name && x.userPass == pass);

        if(user != null)
        {
            this._id = user._id;
            this.userName = user.userName;
            this.userPass = user.userPass;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @CodeCaster, I have edited my answer. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You have to assign it.

```
 user = user.getUser(userName , userPass);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you replace

```
if (user.userName != null)
```

with

```
if ( user.getUser(userName , userPass).userName != null)
```

wil works for you.